# Error #1064 while creating scheduled event

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have a table that stores news. There are two types of news: simple and scheduled news. Scheduled news must be shown every year and must be hidden after 30 days. I can't create a cron job on server, so I decided to use MySQL scheduled events. 
This is my query.

```
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS `update_news`;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE 
EVENT `update_news`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2015-07-15 00:00:00'
DO BEGIN

UPDATE `yakutsk-gf`.`app_news_item` 
SET `date` = DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
WHERE `isCalendar` = '1' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `date`) > 30
ORDER BY `date` DESC;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

But when I try to execute it, MySQL throws an error

```
DELIMITER ;
Ответ MySQL: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1
```

I tried to find ways to fix the problem, but so far nothing found.
FYI, mysql version is 5.5.43-0

Comment: Executed in a slightly newer version (mariadb 10.0.x): No problem at all.

Comment: Likewise - no problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you don't need to change the `DELIMITER` and use `BEGIN...END` block because you have just one statement in the body.

Try it this way

```
CREATE EVENT update_news
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2015-07-15 00:00:00' DO
  UPDATE yakutsk-gf.app_news_item
     SET date = DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
   WHERE isCalendar = '1' 
     AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), date) > 30
   ORDER BY date DESC;
```